# Got stuck with Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I'm writing a simple program in `c` and I'm got stuck with this error

> Segmentation Fault (Core dumped)

I know `Segmentation fault` error occurs due to memory access violation. 
But I'm unable to figure out where in the below simple program bad memory access is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0;   
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}
```

I'm compiling online [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php), In code blocks also it's giving the same error.

Comment: The problem is in the scanf, as pointed out by others, but I'm not sure about the return either.

Comment: @ClaudioCortese `return(0)` is valid, but unnecessary, just `return 0` will do.

Comment: @Weather Wane, didn't know that, LSNED ;)

Comment: @ClaudioCortese in the same way that `int i = (5)` is valid, but you are right, `return` is not a function. My objection would be the `int main()` signature -> `int main(void)`

Comment: @ClaudioCortese, you might also ignore that `int main()` doesn't mean that `main()` takes `0` parameters. But instead it means that `main()` takes an undeterminate number of parameters. So `int main(void)` is really important. Because the only valid signatures for `main()` are `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` and `int main(void);`.

Comment: @iharob I'm now aware of that, thank you!

Comment: @WeatherVane So I was right, return (0) is not valid. Did I understand well?

Comment: @ClaudioCortese I did clearly say `return (0)` *is* valid but it's not very good coding style.

Comment: That's what compiler warnings are for. Enable them and pay heed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok, thank you for your time. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must pass a pointer to `int` instead of the `int` itself. Change it to

```
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1)
    printf("%d\n", a);
else
    printf("Invalid input\n");
```

In your code, `scanf()` is assuming that the value in the `int` is the address it has to write to, leading to *undefined behavior*. Also, another reason for undefined behavior is that `a` wans't initialized before calling `scanf()` but that is irrelevant since anyway *undefined behavior* was going to occur. The standard specifies that any parameter of unexpected type passed to `scanf()` will cause *undefined behavior*.

The fact that `a` was not initialized before calling `scanf()` implies that if you ignore the return value of `scanf()` and it fails, and you try to read `a` like in the `printf()` in your code, your code will invoke *undefined behavior*. That's why it's so important to check the return value.

The `&` *address of* operator makes a pointer containing the address of it's operand, `scanf()` needs a pointer to the parameter<sup>1</sup> in order to be able to store the result in it.

Note that when passing an array for example, a `char` array to `scanf()` a string with the `"%s"` specifier, you should not use the `&` operator because the array name is converted to a poitner to the first element of itself, which is what `scanf()` needs in that case.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note, that there is no *pass by reference* in [c](/questions/tagged/c), so this is the only way you can alter the parameter inside the `scanf()` function.</sub>

Comment: Oops this is what happens when you jump to different programming language. From past few months I'm coding in Python which results in this :)

Comment: @Atinesh No, this is what happens when you don't read carefully the documentation for the functions you use. If you read [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) you will also understand why I compare it's return value to `1`. And always do, ignoring the return value can result in very weird bugs.

Comment: P.S., it should be noted that the int is actually read by `scanf` as a memory address (as if it was a valid pointer), so that the result is written on the memory with the address that == the VALUE of `a` instead of on the memory that is owned by `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
scanf("%d", a);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

[scanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) needs a *pointer* to a variable, not the *value* of a variable.

I can suggest you to add `-Wall` option when you compile.
In your case gcc will warn you:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:25:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", a);
     ^
```